# List sublist deletion based on occurence of a value in subsequent sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a 2D list of the form:

```
{{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2},{a3,b3,c3},...{aN,bN,cN}}
```

I want an efficient way of deleting all sublists if a particular element in the first of those sublists has the same value as that element in the next sublist.

For example, if I have:

```
{{a1,b1,c1},{a2,10,c2},{a3,10,c3},{a4,20,c4},{a5,20,c5},{a6,20,c6}...{aN,bN,cN}}
```

I want to remove the `{a2,10,c2}` and `{a4,20,c4}` sublists to just leave `{{a1,b1,c1},{a3,10,c3},{a5,20,c5},{a6,20,c6}...{aN,bN,cN}}`

I could do this with a Do loop, but it is too slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Each 3-element-sublist in your main list has numeric values in the three positions? It would be helpful if you load a subset/representative sample of your data.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that all list elements are numeric reals.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A few things to try:

```
(*given*)
test = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, 10, c2}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a4, 20, c4}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}};
```

SequenceReplace

```
SequenceReplace[test, {{_, b_, _}, {a_, b_, c_}} :> {a, b, c}]
(*{{a1, b1, c1}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}}*)
```

DeleteDuplicatesBy

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[#[[2]] &][test]
(*{{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, 10, c2}, {a4, 20, c4}, {aN, bN, cN}}*)
```

GroupBy

```
GroupBy[#[[2]] &][test]
(*<|b1 -> {{a1, b1, c1}}, 10 -> {{a2, 10, c2}, {a3, 10, c3}}, 
20 -> {{a4, 20, c4}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}}, 
bN -> {{aN, bN, cN}}|>*)
```

You will need to adjust based on your actual need. It sounds like you want all but the first "match", but I don't know if that's just accidental for this example, and I don't know what other "rules" might exist.

Answer (score 4):

Split then Cases

```
f[{x_}]:=x;
f[{x_,y__}]:=y;
Split[{{a1,b1,c1},{a2,10,c2},{a3,10,c3},{a4,20,c4},{a5,20,c5},{a6,20,c6}},
IntersectingQ]//Map[f]
```

> {{a1,b1,c1},{a3,10,c3},{a5,20,c5},{a6,20,c6}}

Answer (score 4):

```
test = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, 10, c2}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a4, 20, c4},
  {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}};
```

Define a helper function that drops the first element of an input list if its length exceeds 1:

```
reduce = Map[Sequence @@ Drop[#, Boole[Length @ # > 1]] &];
```

We can use `reduce` with [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html),  [`SplitBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) or [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)  as follows:

```
test[[Values @ reduce @ PositionIndex[test[[All, 2]]]]]
```

> ```
> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}}
> ```

```
reduce @ SplitBy[test, #[[2]] &]
```

> ```
> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}}
> ```

```
Values @ GroupBy[test, #[[2]] &, First @ reduce]
```

> ```
> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a6, 20, c6}, {aN, bN, cN}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a suitable pattern and "SequenceReplace":

```
test = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, 10, c2}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a4, 20, c4}, {a5, 
    20, c5}, {a6, b6, 30}, {a7, b7, 30}};
pattern = ({{a_, _, _}, x : {a_, _, _}} | {{_, a_, _}, 
      x : {_, a_, _}} | {{_, _, a_}, x : {_, _, a_}}) -> x;
SequenceReplace[test, pattern]

(* {{a1, b1, c1}, {a3, 10, c3}, {a5, 20, c5}, {a7, b7, 30}} *)
```